# How to restrict ssh users to browse only /home/%u contents

Tags: ssh, chroot

Can I confine my users to their /home/%u directory using only OpenSSH configuration? From instructions I found on the Internet, I stopped the SSH server and appended the following to the `sshd_config` file:

```
Match group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory /home/%u
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

I then started the SSH server again.

FYI I have the users added to `sftpusers` group

My users can still browse i.e `cd /` and are able to use cat command to list file content (`cat /usr/bin/test.sh`) in entire file structure on my system

I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.

Comment: server logs and/or client verbose connection might give more info?

Comment: What are the perms on your home dir?  For `chroot` to work with SSH the home dir must be `root` owned and 755 perm.  Check `auth.log` for some clues.

Comment: Client Logs
-------------------------------
ssh user4@192.168.1.2
user4@192.168.1.2's password: 
Last login: Wed Oct 31 21:37:39 2012 from mylap.local
user4@mahesh:~$ cd /
user4@mahesh:/$ ls /home/user2/
1.log  examples.desktop
user4@mahesh:/$ 
___________________________________
Server configuration is same as mentioned above .(i don't how to attach a file in this site,pls suggest if you know)

/home/ directory permissions have 755

Answer (score 9):

First of all, I would suggest using `ChrootDirectory %h` instead of `/home/%u`, as `%h` expands to the user's home, even if it's no `/home/$USER`.

Now to your actual problem: you need to force `internal-sftp` as the command to be run. The following config works just fine for me, and should also for you:

```
Match group sftp
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

The user's home should be `root`-owned and have 755 permisions as mentioned above:

```
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4.0K Nov 24  2011 /home/testuser
```

Comment: Spent 3 hours yesterday. Simple and efficient solutions. Love you man!!!

Comment: `The user's home should be root-owned and have 755 permisions`, actually it's a "must", not a "should", otherwise the initial connection fails to get established.

Answer (score 1):

### Using `fakechroot`

1. Prepare the user and the directory you want to use for the SSH. For example, you might want to copy some commands from `/bin` directory into the user's `bin` directory. It is considered that the user's name is `test` and user's directory is `/home/test`.
2. Install `fakechroot` package.

   ```
   # Debian-based distros
   sudo apt install fakechroot
   ```
3. Open OpenSSH server configuration file for editing (e.g. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`).
4. Add the following lines to the configuration file (, or replace existing lines if exist):

   ```
   # Replace test with your user of choice
   Match User test
       ForceCommand fakechroot chroot /home/test
       # Other options
   ```
5. Save the file. Start OpenSSH server on the specific port you want. Now, try logging in via SSH. Everything should work as expected.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is old but this helped me.

```
chmod o-x /home/*
```

run the above command from sudo and it will limit a user to its own home dir.

Comment: It looks to me this forbid other to browse your directory, but doesn't confine you to your home dir.

Comment: Yes, that's what it does.